# how to start vuejs ssr server in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, docker-compose, server-side-rendering

I have a vuejs application with @akryum/ssr

While doing

```
npm run ssr:serve
```

or

```
npm run ssr:start
```

everything works as it should. But when I try to use docker:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  npm:
    build:
      context: ./
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.0.0

WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

Only the option without ssr works: npm run serve

Using

```
CMD ["npm", "run", "ssr:start"]
```

i open http://localhost:8080/ and get error

ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

In my package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "ssr:build": "vue-cli-service ssr:build",
    "ssr:serve": "vue-cli-service ssr:serve",
    "ssr:start": "PORT=8080 cross-env NODE_ENV=production vue-cli-service ssr:serve --mode production"
  },
```

On startup I see

```
npm_1  | [16:36:39] Server listening on localhost:8080
```

means the ports are correct

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution!

Added **--host '0.0.0.0'** in package.json

```
"ssr:start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production vue-cli-service ssr:serve --mode production --host '0.0.0.0' --port 8080"
```